# Selenium Java Scroll Bar in section

Tags: javascript, java, scroll

Im trying to move a scroll bar to the right using selenium webdriver in java, in order to focus on an element to get an screenshot, but after trying everything I know, I cannot get it.

The scenario is shown on picture 1:
[sorry for deleting data due to privacy issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRciD.png)

As you may see, scroll is located into the element in blue rectangle,

I've tried this one:

```
     JavascriptExecutor js;
     js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
     js.executeScript("$(\"#Pagination\").animate({ scrollLeft: \"-50000px\" })");
```

Pagination is div id.

Can you help me guys?

Best Regards.

Comment: So, Java or JavaScript?

Comment: @Pavlo Both- WebDriver in Java in which can execute javascript. Yes, there should be added correct tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions' to move to element. It should automatically get element's position x, y and scroll to it.

```
// Initialize instance
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);

// Find element to focus inside iframe
WebElement we = webdriver.findElement("<find element you wish to focus>");

// Perform move action
action.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
```

Haven't tested though, hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

You have two very similar ids - "#Pagina**t**ion" and "#Pagina**c**ion". That is really confusing.
Also, you should consider adding class to rows where you have data, like `data-row`.
**Note:** Be sure that you correctly find the element. As you are displaying table data, that element will be a table cell, not table itself.

**1)** In java code you store script into a string variable:

```
String script = "return $('#Paginacion').find('.data-row').eq(%1$d - 1).find('td').eq(%2$d - 1)";
```

**2)** Then easily pass `rowNumber` and `columnNumber` to `executeScript`
    method. 
    Note: Should add also null checks.

```
int rowNumber = 1;
int columnNumber = 19;

List<WebElement> webElements = (List<WebElement>)js.executeScript(String.format(script, rowNumber, columnNumber));
```

**3)** When element found, just call `moveToElement` method

```
action.moveToElement((WebElement) webElements.get(0)).build().perform();
```

Tested and it works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it doesnt work, since the scrollbar does not move from start position.

It seems like the table with the scroll is already visible, so focusing on it does not move the scroll bar.

Any other option, dudes? Thank you.

Comment: @user6648978 Could you please create a small sample html in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) similar, how it is in your project?

Comment: Here you are.
https://jsfiddle.net/51463j0g/
Lets suppose I want to move the scroll until element under number 19 in table appears on screen.

Comment: @user6648978 Please see Edit.

Comment: This part:
`WebElement we = ((webdriver as JavaScriptExecutor)
    .executeScript(String.format(script, rowNumber, columnNumber)) as List<WebElement>)[0];`
dont know how to translate into JAVA :(

Comment: @DPSeen Updated fully to java syntax.